# Convert Month Year to YYYY-MM-DD date format Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

i want to convert Month and year to YYYY-MM-DD in a dataframe in panda, the date will be the first day of that month

[image]

i try using this

```
pd.to_datetime(df, format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='ignore')
```

I expected the result to be

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with format `'%b,%Y'`:

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b,%Y', errors='coerce')
```

OR

Don't use format at all and let `pandas` infer it:

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')
```

For more info regarding format code see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)